# Does Sonarqube support GO lang, if not then when does that feature come into place

Tags: go, sonarqube

I need to analyse my code against Sonarqube 5.1, is there a way to do this, if not when will this feature come handy with sonar.

Comment: You could create a Sonarqube plugin for GO, yourself.

Comment: How to do that, can you please guide me with that

Comment: I've never done this myself. But there should be tutorials on how to. Probably, you will have to analyse plugins for other languages, too, in order to understand how plugins work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Go plugin for SonarQube for the time being and I'm not aware of a plan to have this plugin in the upcoming months.

Comment: There is a now Go plugin available from SonarSource -- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-go